# Splines and clinical dataset query

Tags: dataset, splines, regression-strategies

Perhaps off topic or not directly suitable for crossvalidated but does anyone know of a good dataset with a clinical aspect I could use to teach myself how to use regression splines (in R)? I always find learning new methods easier if I have something concrete to my discipline to analyse.

Answer (score 3):

The SUPPORT study of critically ill patients with lots of great continuous predictors (e.g., physiologic measurements such as serum creatinine) and four types of outcome variables is a terrific learning dataset.  For a data dictionary see http://hbiostat.org/data/repo/Csupport.html.  There is a full 9000 patient dataset and a random sample of 1000 patients that you might start with.  See http://hbiostat.org/data under SUPPORT Datasets.  You can load annotated datasets directly into R from the web if you have the `Hmisc` package installed:

```
require(Hmisc)
getHdata(support)   # downloads support and load()s it
```

My course notes has a case study using the 1000 patient dataset - see http://hbiostat.org/rmsc

Comment: Frank, thanks for these great resources. Looking forward to digging into this.